# Add UIPageControl to UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I have a UIScrollView containing 5 images. I want to add a UIPageControl at the bottom of my scroll view so that the user can see what page they are on.

Here is my code for the scroll view:

```
self.helpScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320 * 5, 436);

UIImageView *image1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(320 * 0, 0, 320, 436)];
image1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:
                                   @"Guide Page One.png"]];
[self.helpScrollView addSubview:image1];

UIImageView *image2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(320 * 1, 0, 320, 436)];
image2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:
                                    @"Guide Page Two.png"]];
[self.helpScrollView addSubview:image2];

UIImageView *image3 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(320 * 2, 0, 320, 436)];
image3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:
                                    @"Guide Page Three.png"]];
[self.helpScrollView addSubview:image3];

UIImageView *image4 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(320 * 3, 0, 320, 436)];
image4.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:
                                    @"Guide Page Four.png"]];
[self.helpScrollView addSubview:image4];

UIImageView *image5 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(320 * 4, 0, 320, 436)];
image5.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:
                                    @"Guide Page Five.png"]];
[self.helpScrollView addSubview:image5];

self.helpScrollView.pagingEnabled = true;
self.helpScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
```

I have dragged a UIPageControl onto my scrollview in my xib file, but I don't know how to link them. How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't want to add the `UIPageControl` to the scroll view itself because you don't want it to scroll with the content.

With that said, take a look at the `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol, specifically `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:` which will be called when your scroll view stops moving (a good time to update your `UIPageControl`).

Your calculation is going to be something like..

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
   self.pageControl.currentPage = floorf(scrollView.contentOffSet.x/320);
}
```

**Re: I have two scroll views within one view controller, so does this specify which one I'm using?**

The `scrollView` instance passed in can be used to negotiate which scroll view did end decelerating. If you set the `delegate` property for both of your scroll views this will get called when either of those end decelerating so you'll need to verify which instance ended decelerating.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
   if (scrollView == self.helpScrollView) {
       self.pageControl.currentPage = floorf(scrollView.contentOffset.x/scrollView.frame.size.width);
   }
}
```

Comment: I do my pagecontrol updating inside scrollViewDidScroll to get a more responsive pagecontrol, but either one works (mine just takes more processing power).

Comment: Yeah, you can do it in there also.

Comment: I have two scroll views within one view controller, so does this specify which one I'm using?

Comment: It seems like the method is being called, but I can't see my UIPageControl?

Comment: How did you add it to your view? Did you wire it up to your property?

Comment: I made this property: @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIPageControl *pageControl; and connected it through the xib. I didn't put it inside the scroll view, but on top of it.

Comment: Are you sure it is actually "above" (z-index) the scroll view? In the outline view it should be listed below (after) your scroll view.

Comment: Ahh, that's why!! Sorry about that!!